# Multiple action handlers of Buttons gets fired, only when the parent VStack is inside a List in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

*Case 1*:- When I have multiple Buttons in a VStack, on clicking of any one of them, the action handlers of both the buttons executes immediately, this happens only when the VStack is a child of List.
For eg-

```
List {
            VStack {
                Button(action: { print("A") }) {
                Text("Button A")
                }

                Button(action: { print("B") }) {
                Text("Button B")
                }
            }
        }
```

Here when you click on any one Button(say Button B), the o/p is:- 
*A*
*B*

*Case 2*:- Try that with just a VStack, it works fine.
For eg-

```
VStack {
            Button(action: { print("C") }) {
            Text("Button C")
            }

            Button(action: { print("D") }) {
            Text("Button D")
            }
        }
```

Here when you click on any one Button(say Button D), the o/p is:-
*D*

I am new to iOS programming, please help me understand where I am going wrong or is it an issue with SwiftUI?

Answer (score 11):

Set the button style to something different from the default, e.g., BorderlessButtonStyle()

```
struct Test: View {
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      List {
        ForEach([
          "Line 1",
          "Line 2",
        ], id: \.self) {
          item in
          HStack {
            Text("\(item)")
            Spacer()
            Button(action: { print("\(item) 1")}) {
              Text("Button 1")
            }
            Button(action: { print("\(item) 2")}) {
              Text("Button 2")
            }
          }
        }
        .onDelete { _ in }
        .buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
      }
      .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
    }
    .accentColor(.red)
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes i tested your suggestion and also few other `ButtonStyles` and found that only `DefaultButtonStyle` has this issue. If we apply other Styles to Button it works fine. Still not sure if it's a bug or intended behaviour. Thanks though.

Comment: Changing the button style also solved my issue.

Comment: This bug is still exist in iOS 16.2...

Comment: Bug still exists today with latest version.

Comment: latest iOS 16.4 and this is still around, almost freaked out from this

Answer (score 2):

Buttons inside List won't work as expected. Most likely a bug, but not acknowledge officially. Since it wasn't acknowledge, nobody can tell when/if it's going to be fixed.

In the meantime, you may use a custom button, like the one below. It replicates the Button behavior (color and dimming on tap):

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var flag = false

    var body: some View {
        List {
            VStack {
                MyButton(label: "Button A") {
                    print("A")
                }

                MyButton(label: "Button B") {
                    print("B")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MyButton: View {
    @State private var tapped = false
    let label: String
    let action: () -> ()

    var body: some View {
        let g = DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .local)
            .onChanged({ _ in
                withAnimation { self.tapped = true }
            })
            .onEnded({ _ in
                withAnimation { self.tapped = false }
                self.action()
            })

        return Text(label)
            .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.link)
                .opacity(tapped ? 0.5 : 1.0))
            .gesture(g)


    }
}
```

Comment: I know the workaround, just wanted to know if this is an issue with SwiftUI(which'll be fixed later) or there's something I don't know conceptually.
Also the Buttons doesn't hold their Blue colour appearance when inside a List and looks just like a simple Text.

Comment: I updated the answer, to include a working button (color and dimming on tap included.

Comment: Also note that it is most likely a bug, but not acknowledge officially. Since it wasn't acknowledge, nobody can tell when/if it's going to be fixed.